# Functional Contractions?

Tags: meaning-in-context

When I was on a walk next to a river, I saw stickers on the railings showing a picture of a hand holding a weight and text below it saying "Functional Contractions". Doing a google search shows results about muscles in the human body contracting, but I do not understand why the sticker would be there if it was not related to political or propaganda matters.

Comment: It was probably just spam.

Comment: @Chenmunka what do you mean? It was in the real world.

Comment: Perhaps it is advertising the name of a local gym or weight training centre.  Where exactly was this? can you provide a photograph?

Comment: Or, just as likely, it is advertising this youtube channel https://www.youtube.com/@functionalcontractions1469/videos

Comment: @JamesK I do not wish to disclose my location.

Comment: Your choice.  You'll get better answers if you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very probably a form of 'street art'. The words don't have to mean anything.

[image]